# How to efficiently broadcast multiplication between arrays of shapes (n,m,k) and (n,m)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let `a` be a `numpy` array of shape `(n,m,k)` and `a_msk` is an array of shape `(n,m)` containing that masks elements from a through *multiplication*.

Up to my knowledge, I had to create a new axis in `a_msk` in order to make it compatible with `a` for multiplication.

```
b = a * a_msk[:,:,np.newaxis]
```

Unfortunately, my Google Colab runtime is running out of memory at this very operation given the large size of the arrays.

My question is whether I can achieve the same thing without creating that new axis for the mask array.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way to do that multiplication.  And, yes it is possible to use arrays that are too big.  My guess is that you barely have room for `a` and and another array of the same size.   Broadcasting doesn't increase the size of `a_msk`, but you will need space to store `b`.

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj commented adding an axis to make the two arrays "compatible" for broadcasting is the most straightforward way to do your multiplication.

Alternatively, you can move the last axis of your array `a` to the front which would also make the two arrays compatible (I wonder though whether this would solve your memory issue):

```
a = np.moveaxis(a, -1, 0)
```

Then you can simply multiply:

```
b = a * a_msk
```

However, to get your result you have to move the axis back:

```
b = np.moveaxis(b, 0, -1)
```

Example: both solutions return the same answer:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 3, 4)
a_msk = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)

print(f'newaxis solution:\n {a * a_msk[..., np.newaxis]}')
print()
print(f'moveaxis solution:\n {np.moveaxis((np.moveaxis(a, -1, 0) * a_msk), 0, -1)}')
```